# Что значит (int*)

Tags: c

Например

```
pry = (int*)i;
```

Или такое

```
void(*st)(void)
```

Я знаю, что это указатель, но только если при объявлении переменной.

Comment: Если я все правильно помню, то это так называемый каст или приведение типов - при создании указателей не всегда сразу получается их объявить с верным типом, поэтому передают void*, а уже в необходимом месте переводят в нужный тип. Если не ошибаюсь, то тот же `malloc()` так работает.

Comment: @Fangog, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 11):

Строка первая: приведение типа i к типу *указатель на int*.

Строка вторая: объявление *указателя на функцию* типа void f(void) с именем указателя st.